# How to select a specific html node with a jquery selector and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html table:

```
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td class="rich-tabpanel-content">
         <table>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <span class="bold">Overview</span>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <input class="titleInput" type="text"></input>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <span class="bold">Shorttext</span>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <textarea class="shorttextInput"></textarea>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <span class="bold">Longtext</span>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <textarea class="longtextInput"></textarea>
                  </td>
               </tr>
           </tbody>
        </table>
     </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Now i want to select these tags in DOM:

```
<span class="bold">Overview</span>
<span class="bold">Shorttext</span>
<span class="bold">Longtext</span>
```

I have written these line of JQuery and Java Script Code to change the value of these HTML Tags, but the command

```
"jQuery(value).parent().prev();"
```

doesn´t select the right html tag in the DOM:

```
jQuery('.titleInput').each(function(index, value) {
selectAndExpand(value);
}

function selectAndExpand(value) {
var captionCell = jQuery(value).parent().prev();
captionCell.empty();
var newCaption = '<span class="bold">' + "HERE IS MY NEW INPUTVALUE" + '</span>';
captionCell.append(newCaption);
};
```

How can i solve this problem?

It is important to navigate for example from the node

```
<textarea class="longtextInput"></textarea>
```

to

```
<span class="bold">Longtext</span>
```

or from

```
<input class="titleInput" type="text"></input>
```

to

```
<span class="bold">Overview</span>
```

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j3yFw/1/

Comment: Check my answers. I added working demo for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21155347/1278667

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$('.bold').each(function(){
$(this).html("HERE IS MY NEW INPUTVALUE")
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f4yqa/)**

Answer (score 0):

use [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) in your case use `$('.bold')` to select the span class `bold` and you can easily navigate to [prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) and [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/) like `$('.bold').parent('tr').next().find('.bold');` and also give the bold class to your input elements so that we can easily navigate.

Comment: but "$('.bold').next()" select all available span tags like "Overview", "Shorttext" and "Longtext". How can i navigate for example only from "<textarea class="shorttextInput"></textarea>" to "<span class="bold">Shorttext</span>" and don´t change the other existings html tags by using my JQuery and JavaScript code?

Comment: This code "JQuery(shorttextInput).parent('tr').next().find('.bold')" navigates only to "<span class="bold">Shorttext</span>"?

Comment: I've also said to add class bold to that input so it would be very easy to navigate.

Comment: Sorry but i don´t understand your jqeury selector rule in my complex java script coding

Comment: But i don´t have the class "bold" in "<textarea class="shorttextInput"></textarea>" and it is not possible to rename this class attribut.

Comment: You can add another class like this class="shorttextInput bold"

Comment: ok you right but the classname "shorttextInput" cannot be changed since this is a customer project of my company. If there are no other ways to select the html tags? Thanks and Greetz Marwief

Answer (score 0):

You can select them by class name (when the class name is the same, in your case "bold"):

```
$(".bold");
```

To select all textareas after them and set values to these "bold" - element use

```
var spans = $(".bold");

$.each(spans, function(index, item) {
    var spanTd = $(item).closest("tr");
    var value = $(spanTd).next().find("textarea").val();
    if (value === undefined) { //if there aren't textarea - get textbox.
          value = $(spanTd).next().find("input[type='text']").val();
    }
    $(item).html(value);
});
```

EDIT: Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/h9fpy/

Comment: Hi ! Is it possible to work in your solution with "jquery()" instead of "$()" ?

Answer (score 0):

With Javascript:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('bold');
console.log(elements[0]);
console.log(elements[1]);
console.log(elements[2]);
```

With jQuery:

```
var elements = $('.bold');
console.log(elements[0]);
console.log(elements[1]);
console.log(elements[2]);
```

or...

```
console.log($('td:contains("Overview")'));
console.log($('td:contains("Shorttext")'));
console.log($('td:contains("Longtext")'));
```

Cheers.